# Why my form is not visible when I am adding if-else block in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why my form is not visible after filling submit button  and when I am removing these line of codes form is visible:

```
 if (data.trim() === 'Done') {
     $("#msg").html("Succesfully Registered !!!"); 
     $("#msg").addClass("green-text");
 } else  {
     $("#msg").html("Something went wrong !!!");
     $("#msg").addClass("red-text");}
```

I cross-checked it many times but it is not working please help

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
            
    </head>
    <body style="background-image: url(images/bg.jpg); background-size: cover;background-attachment: fixed;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col m6 offset-m3">
                    
                    <div class="card">
                         <div class="card-content">
                             <div class="form center-align">
                                 <h3 style="margin-top: 10px;"class="center-align">Register Here !!</h3>
                                 <h5 id="msg" class="center-align"</h5>
                                <div class="form">
                                <!-- creating form -->
                                <form action="Register" method="post" id="myform">
                                    <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Enter user_name"\>
                                    <input type="password" name="user_password" placeholder="Enter password"\>
                                    <input type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Enter your email"\>
                                    
                                    <button type="submit" name="btn" style="background-color:#b3e5fc;">Submit</button>
                                    
                                </form>
                                
                            </div>
                    </div>
                             <div class="loader center-align" style="margin-top: 10px; display: none;" >
                                        <div class="preloader-wrapper big active">
                                            <div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue-only">
                                              <div class="circle-clipper left">
                                                <div class="circle"></div>
                                              </div><div class="gap-patch">
                                                <div class="circle"></div>
                                              </div><div class="circle-clipper right">
                                                <div class="circle"></div>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                      
                                            
                                    <h5>Please Wait....</h5>
                                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
                
        </script>
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log("Page is ready...... ") ;
                $("#myform").on('submit',function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var f = $(this).serialize();
                console.log(f);
                $(".loader").show();
                $(".form").hide();
                     
                    $.ajax({
                       url:"Register",
                       data:f,
                       type:'POST',
                       success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
                           console.log(data);
                           console.log("Success......");
                           $(".loader").hide();
                           $(".form").show();
                           if (data.trim() === 'Done') 
                           {
                            $("#msg").html("Succesfully Registered !!!");
                            $("#msg").addClass("green-text");
                          } 
                          else 
                          {
                            $("#msg").html("Something went wrong !!!");
                            $("#msg").addClass("red-text");
                          }

                       },
                       error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
                           console.log(data);
                           console.log("error");
                           $(".loader").hide();
                           $(".form").show();
                           $("#msg").html("Something went wrong !!!");
                           $("#msg").addClass("red-text");
                       }
                   });   
                });
                });
       
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us what's your `console.log(data);` look like ?

Comment: Edit your post, and show us only the `console.log(data)` not the other console.log please :)

Comment: You forgot to close the first `h5` tag after the class here, I don't know if it has an impact : `<h5 id="msg" class="center-align"</h5>`

Comment: @jean-max when I am removing if else block it works fine I think error is something in this code

Comment: Did you close the `h5` tag ? I think it's because of that

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="background-image: url(images/bg.jpg); background-size: cover;background-attachment: fixed;">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col m6 offset-m3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="form center-align">
                        <h3 style="margin-top: 10px;" class="center-align">Register Here !!</h3>
                        <h5 id="msg" class="center-align"></h5>
                        <div class="form">
                            <!-- creating form -->
                            <form action="Register" method="post" id="myform">
                                <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Enter user_name" />
                                <input type="password" name="user_password" placeholder="Enter password" />
                                <input type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Enter your email" />

                                <button type="submit" name="btn" style="background-color:#b3e5fc;">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="loader center-align" style="margin-top: 10px; display: none;">
                        <div class="preloader-wrapper big active">
                            <div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue-only">
                                <div class="circle-clipper left">
                                    <div class="circle"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="gap-patch">
                                    <div class="circle"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="circle-clipper right">
                                    <div class="circle"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <h5>Please Wait....</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
        crossorigin="anonymous">

</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('Page is ready...... ');
    $('#myform').on('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var f = $(this).serialize();
      console.log(f);
      $('.loader').show();
      $('.form').hide();

      $.ajax({
        url: 'Register',
        data: f,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          console.log(data);
          console.log('Success......');
          $('.loader').hide();
          $('.form').show();
          if (data.trim() === 'Done') {
            $('#msg').html('Succesfully Registered !!!');
            $('#msg').addClass('green-text');
          } else {
            $('#msg').html('Something went wrong !!!');
            $('#msg').addClass('red-text');
          }

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(data);
          console.log('error');
          $('.loader').hide();
          $('.form').show();
          $('#msg').html('Something went wrong !!!');
          $('#msg').addClass('red-text');
        }
      });
    });
  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks it is working now what was the error please show me :)

Comment: It's the `h5` tag that was not closed. Missing this `>` after `align"` : <h5 id="msg" class="center-align"></h5>

Comment: thanks  a lot  very small mistake spoiled my whole day have a nice day  :)